# How to manipulate data if data fetched from API is not JSON but instead html

Tags: javascript, url, fetch-api

I want to access a public website using its URL, and modify/download its content (images) from my code.
This is a personal quest don't know that if it is even possible or not.

Code to fetch data from website URL:

[image: 1]

I have tried to fetch the URL but it returns a html instead of JSON. Now I have a html body on my console but I don't know how to access data from it.

Before coming here I tried to searching the way to do it but still haven't found a way to do it.

Resulted fetched data:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

If you want get specific data from a HTMLDocument/XMLDocument you need to manage like that.
Code patterns and scripts to get values of textNodes and Document elements you found in the Document and save it on objects you can manipulate after recollect all the information you need.

```
tbody = document.getElementsByClassName("bolt-table bolt-table-show-lines bolt-list body-m relative scroll-hidden")[0];
tbody.childNodes.forEach(e => {
    if( e.childNodes.length > 1){    
        console.log(e.childNodes[1].tagName);
    }
});
```

Something like the code above in which we found a pattern to access the needed data and create a script to get them and output in some way.

NOTE: code is just an example to show what kind of thing we can do to get the data, you should to create specific code based on HTMLDocument/XMLDocument structure you have. You might need to use extra APIs or js tools to manipulate the Document elements.